# Python: Split, strip, and join in one line

Tags: python, join, split, list-comprehension, trim

I'm curious if their is some python magic I may not know to accomplish a bit of frivolity

given the line:

```
csvData.append(','.join([line.split(":").strip() for x in L]))
```

I'm attempting to split a line on `:`, trim whitespace around it, and join on `,`

problem is, since the array is returned from `line.split(":")`, the

```
for x in L #<== L doesn't exist!
```

causes issues since I have no name for the array returned by `line.split(":")`

So I'm curious if there is a sexy piece of syntax I could use to accomplish this in one shot?

Cheers!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
>>> line = 'a: b :c:d:e  :f:gh   '
>>> ','.join(x.strip() for x in line.split(':'))
'a,b,c,d,e,f,gh'
```

You can also do this:

```
>>> line.replace(':',',').replace(' ','')
'a,b,c,d,e,f,gh'
```

Comment: I actually prefer the first answer, as the second is less robust to what the whitespace is.

Comment: First answer, Awesome!

Comment: @DSM How about `for sp in [' ', '\n', '\t']: line = line.replace(sp, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Something like?:

```
>>> L = "1:2:3:4"
>>> result = ",".join([item.strip() for item in L.split(":")])
>>> result
'1,2,3,4'
```

It takes awhile to get a grasp on list comprehensions.  They are basically just packaged loops when you break them down.

So, when learning, try to break it down as a normal loop, and then translate it to a list comprehension.

In your example you don't assign the `line` variable anywhere, so it would be an error even in a standard loop.

```
>>> for x in L:
...     items = line.split(":")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: No need to build a list in the middle

Comment: Yes, true, but for a beginner it may be confusing as to why that works.

Answer (score 1):

Given an string S:

```
','.join([x.strip() for x in s.split(':')])
```

Comment: no need of  list comprehension here, just `','.join(x.strip() for x in s.split(':'))`.

Comment: True, although the list comprehension may clarify part of the solution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary how is your answer different?