# Splitting a list into other lists if a full stop is found

Tags: python, string, list, split

Given this list:

```
['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']
```

How could i return lists separated by a full stop? returning this:

```
['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.'][ 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
[s.strip().split() + ["."] for s in " ".join(l).split(".") if s]
```

1. join with spaces
2. split on periods
3. include only those items that are not empty
4. include items that are a joined list of

   - stripped sentences
   - resplit by spaces
   - appended by a last item period

output:

```
[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.'], ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop:

```
l = ['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']

out = [[]]
for i, e in enumerate(l):
    out[-1].append(e)
    if e == '.' and i+1 != len(l):
        out.append([])
```

output:

```
[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.'],
 ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a generator:

```
def sentences_generator(lst):
    sentence = []
    for w in lst:
        sentence.append(w)
        if w == '.':
            yield sentence
            sentence = []
```

And then I would use it in this way (`lst` is your list of words):

```
sentences = list(sentences_generator(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the join-split method, as detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381408/python-split-strip-and-join-in-one-line).

```
old_list = ['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']
new_list = [item.strip().split() + ["."] for item in " ".join(old_list).split(".") if item]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.'], ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']]
```

Comment: It looks remarkably similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70926524/2081835).

Answer (score 0):

You can join the elements in your list into a string and then split in the way that you want

```
a=['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']
a=" ".join(a) # joins the list into a string separated by spaces
a=a.split(".") # splits the string over the "." character
a=[x.lstrip(" ").rstrip(" ").split(" ") for x in a if len(x)>0] # splits the elements of the array and removes any empty elements
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly'], ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using itertools.groupby.  The group numbers would be formed by alternating True/False based on items being the stop value or not.

```
from itertools import groupby

R = [list(g)+['.'] for d,g in groupby(L,lambda n:n!='.') if d]

print(R)

[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 
  'very', 'pythonly', '.'],
 ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']]
```

*Note that there will always be a `'.'` at the end of each group in the output even if the last item doesn't end with a `'.'`.  Also, this will not output empty groups between two `'.'` items.*

For a more generalized solution that includes empty groups and doesn't add any extra `'.'`, you can use accumulate to obtain a new group number after each `'.'` item encountered:

```
from itertools import chain, accumulate, groupby

group = chain([0],accumulate(c=='.' for c in L))
R = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(L,lambda _:next(group))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', 
   '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']
a=" ".join(a).split(".") 
a=[x.lstrip(" ").rstrip(" ").split(" ") for x in a if len(x)>0] 
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner using [`more_itertools.split_after`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_after):

```
result = list(split_after(lst, '.'.__eq__))
```

Full demo:

```
from more_itertools import split_after

lst = ['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.', 'Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']

result = list(split_after(lst, '.'.__eq__))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Pythoners', 'are', 'very', 'intelligent', 'and', 'work', 'very', 'pythonly', '.'], ['Now', 'they', 'are', 'pythoning', 'their', 'way', 'to', 'success', '.']]
```